# MVC 5 DateTime POST to Controller showing as 1/1/0001

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having some issues with editing a model from the scaffold created view and controller created using a database first model when the model has a DateTime field.  Creating a new record works fine. When trying to edit the newly created record will bring in the proper date and time in the generated edit page.  The problem occurs when I try to save the record back to the database.  The model on the controller shows the created while debugging shows the DateTime field as 1/1/0001 12:00:00.  I am not sure what would be causing this issue as I am using the standard generated code for the Model View and Controller.  In the autos window while debugging I see under ValueProvider that the Key has the correct ValidatedResult as well.

Here is the model code as generated from the entity framework

```
    public partial class Feature
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Feature()
    {
        this.FeatureActions = new HashSet<FeatureAction>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool InActive { get; set; }
    public bool System { get; set; }
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<FeatureAction> FeatureActions { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the method on the controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description,InActive,System,Version,CreatedDate,UpdatedDate")] Feature feature)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            feature.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            db.Entry(feature).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(feature);
    }
```

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: What is the actual date value as it is passed in the network requests?

Comment: The actual value I am passing in is like this "7/21/2015 10:32:21 AM" it is the value that is pulled from the database and displayed in the EditorFor field in Razor I have tried to modify the value as well and it always shows on the controller model as 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Are you using some third-party plugin like datetimepicker?

Comment: I am not using any 3rd party plugins, it is just the generated code from the scaffolding

Comment: Whenever I encounter this problem it is usually because the value, as seen in the raw network request, is null or in a format string that .NET cannot parse into a date. You can also trace the value before you run it through your EF update and even watch the generated SQL query.

Comment: If the value is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` then its not binding which means either your view is wrong (the `name` attribute of the control does not match the name of you model property) or the culture on the server does not match the format of the value your posting (your posting `MM/dd/yyyy` but the server culture is one that expects say `dd/MM/yyyy`). But the only 2 date properties you have are `CreateDate` and `UpdateDate`, neiher of which should be editable by the user so use a view model (that excludes those properties)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a third-party plugin like datetimepicker, you have to see what the datetime format for this plugin is on.

If I understood the problem, these plugins has a default format than whether the format received is not compatible, It put the default.

Hope this give you some help. :)

Comment: it is a core issue. not a 3rd party one

Answer (score 0):

Usually if the DateTime valued is display like `1/1/0001 12:00:00` then the binding is wrong (maybe a misspelled name).. but with the way your properties are named, it looks like the user shouldn't be able to edit those values, which is what I see in your controller with `feature.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now`

In your model try:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy, hh.mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy, hh.mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: This solution doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 input type="date" shows date as yyyy-MM-dd. so first you need to change your date format by:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Second, the DateTime that not accept null will take the initial value DateTime.MinValue which return Date = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}
so make your datetime accept null by `public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }`
and if your datetime in the database not accept null, On your model class decorate that property with `[Required]` attribute

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Created Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
```